# Azure AppInsights alert notifications of warnings

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have the following Azure function:

```
    [FunctionName("FunctionSync")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger _log) // where ILogger is Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger
    {

        try
        {
            // some code
        }
        catch (VerizonUnexpectedResponseException ex)
        {
            log.LogError($"{ex.Message}; response text: '{ex.ResponseText}'");
        }
        catch(VerizonUnsuccessfulResponseException failed_ex)
        {
            log.LogWarning($"Unexpected response; Error: '{failed_ex.Response.Error}', Description: '{failed_ex.Response.Description}'");
        }
    }
```

So, I wrote to AI some messages as Warning and Error when some conditions are true...
Right now I want to create Alert notifications (to email, for example), I go to Azure App Insights -> Rules -> Create New Rule and I don't understand which Signal Name should I select for it?

[image]

Comment: hello, if the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Custom log search, where the search could be something like

```
traces
| where message contains "some recognizable part of your message"
```

or

```
exceptions
| where type contains "VerizonUnexpectedResponseException" 
  or type contains "VerizonUnsuccessfulResponseException"
```

Comment: no-no, I want to select all messages, saved as warning or error using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`

Comment: so, your log messages will appear under `traces`, what you need to do is determine what's in there that you can filter on (and I can't see all of that from here). Try this: Go to Application Insights for your app, then "Logs". A popup of quick queries will appear - dismiss that. Then enter `traces` in the query editor and run it. If what you need to filter on is there, you can reference those values, otherwise you may need to customize your logging to get the information you need recorded.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `custom log search`.

When create the alert rule, for `resources`, you should select the connected `Application Insights` instead of the `function app`. Then for `Condition`, select `Custom log search`.

As per your code, both the messages from `log.LogError` and `log.LogWarning` will be flowed into traces table. For messages from `log.LogError`, the `severityLevel` property will be set as 3; For messages from `log.LogWarning`, the `severityLevel` property will be set as 2. And you can also use `cloud_RoleName`(here, it should be your function app name) property to identify your function app.

So in `Custom log search`, the query should look like below:

```
traces 
| where severityLevel in (2,3)
| where cloud_RoleName == "function app name"
```

Then you can continue configure other settings for this alert rule.